# Send SQL query to individual receiver

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 10 consultants where I would like to send a email-report every Friday night with what they have reported that they worked (report) on a weekly basis.

This report should be sent in an email where the results are displayed in mailbody (not attached)

Right now I only managed to do a report that I send to everyone with every consult included, and I put everyones email-addresses in @recipients. But from now I will send individual report to every consult with only they own result.

Please help me in the right direction. This is what I have so far. No problem to join theirs email-address to the query.

```
DECLARE @bodyMsg nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @subject nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @tableHTML nvarchar(max)

SET @subject = 'Weekly report - Consult'


SET @tableHTML = 
N'<h1 style="color: #4485b8; font-family:Arial;">Weekly report - Consult</h1>' +
N'<table style="width: 600px; font-family:Arial; float: left;" border="1" cellpadding="5">' +
N'<tr style="height: 21px; font-family:Arial;">
<th></th>
<th style="text-align:left;">Consult</th>
<th style="text-align:left;">Last</th>
<th style="text-align:right;">Time</th>
<th style="text-align:right;">Amount</th>
</tr>' +

CAST ( ( 

SELECT 
td = OrdLn.R1,'',
td = R1.Nm,'',
td = MAX(OrdLn.TrDt),'',
td = CAST(ROUND(SUM(NoInvoAb + NoInvo),2) as int),'',
td = CAST(ROUND(SUM(DInvoSF + DInvoIF),0) as int),''

FROM OrdLn
LEFT JOIN R1 ON R1.RNo = OrdLn.R1
LEFT JOIN Prod ON Prod.ProdNo = OrdLn.ProdNo
WHERE Prod.Gr3 > 0
    AND OrdLn.R1 <= '990'
    AND OrdLn.R1 > '0'
    AND OrdLn.TrDt >= CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0),112))
    AND OrdLn.TrDt <= CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()), 6),112))
GROUP BY OrdLn.R1
    ,R1.Nm
ORDER BY OrdLn.R1 ASC


FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>' 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='john.doe@domain.com',
@profile_name = 'Mikael', 
@subject = @subject,
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML'
```

Comment: Without having table definitions clearly stating what fields mean what (e.g. the consultant ID, name, email address and so on) and what the relations between the tables are, the question is still unclear. There isn't much we could answer except for vague outlines of what you should do. I suppose the easiest would probably to create a loop on the consultants  (using a cursor) where you do the procedure you included in your question.

Comment: Sorry, my swedish to english isn´t better so please delete my post.